# QtCreator stucks on starting the .exe file when clicked on Run

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I made a simple console Qt application using QtCreator. It built fine and generated a .exe file in the build folders, and when I double click on the .exe file, it runs properly 
displaying a simple text message. But weirdly, when I click on the run button inside QtCreator, I see the message in the console - `16:13:27: Starting C:\build-HelloWorldConsole-Desktop_Qt_6_1_3_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\HelloWorldConsole.exe ...`
And that's all. It just stuck there. Ideally it should open a console window with the 
text message similar to the one displayed when directly clicked on the .exe file. I am not sure why it's not opening the black window when run inside the qt-creator.
What could be missing in the setup?

Comment: Is it stuck or it has finished execution? just check in "application output" window msg might be printed there.